# How to remove flutter observatory debugger and profiler for linux release?

Tags: flutter

I am creating linux application and want remove flutter observatory debugger and profiler from final release.
I added this on main.dart:

```
MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false
)
```

But, It's only remove banner from application.
While i try to run (release):

```
user@user:~/Desktop/linux/myapp/build/linux/release$./myapp
flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:36177/4MsXpokkp9k=/
```

Comment: `$flutter run -d linux` to run application. `$flutter build linux` to build application. Which will located at `yourapp/build/linux/release/`.But as @smorgan explained "only debug mode is currently supported for Linux".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below is no longer relevant to current versions of Flutter. Release mode is now supported, so a release build will not have the observatory.

---

> from final release
> [...]
> While i try to run (release)

Hopefully you saw the giant banner when you built saying that what you are building is effectively debug mode, and the documentation saying that only debug mode is currently supported for Linux. There is essentially no difference between the debug and release builds right now. You should not be attempting to make a "final release" on Linux; there's no way to do so.

It is possible to disable the observatory via engine argument. You can also disable checked mode, instead of running in checked mode (where asserts will still fire) while turning off the banner warning that you are doing so. To do both you'd add this to your main.cc:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  arguments.push_back("--disable-observatory");
  arguments.push_back("--disable-dart-asserts");
#endif
```

That still won't give you a release builds though; it'll give you a debug build with a couple of features disabled. The way to actually make a release build (which would, among other things, already have those things disabled) is to wait for [release mode support](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38478).