# Console Messages in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-android, flutter-debug

I am currently in the master channel in Flutter on Version  2.6.0-12.0.pre.406 and every time i run an app im getting these strange messages in the console and i just wanna know why and what they mean and if i can ignore these. This even happens when i am newly creating an app and run it without editing anything. So even when i am running the example app.

This is the output:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ... in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              7,0s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
Syncing files to device ...                                 98ms
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on ... is available at: http://127.0.0.1:59402/M3bn7N7nUow=/
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/Gralloc4(25682): mapper 4.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3(25682): mapper 3.x is not supported
I/gralloc (25682): Arm Module v1.0
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@ba09739  isViewVisible: true
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler onv... is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:59402/M3bn7N7nUow=/
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] pd() Asnyc report
I/SurfaceView(25682): setParentSpaceRectangle: useBLAST = false position = Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3020) frameNumber = 1 t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@89f17e
I/SurfaceView(25682): applySurfaceTransforms: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@89f17e surfaceControl = Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.example.randomdice2/com.example.randomdice2.MainActivity@761f583@0)/@0x7c466df frame = 1
I/SurfaceView(25682): applySurfaceTransforms: postScaleX = 1.0 postScaleY = 1.0
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938
I/ViewRootImpl@963f43d[MainActivity](25682): [DP] rdf()
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried googling this? Could you provide more information about what exactly is unclear in this output?

Comment: Yes i tried googling it but i found nothing. I just wanna know why this pops up and what this could mean because this messages werent there from the beginning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914114/how-to-remove-flutter-observatory-debugger-and-profiler-for-linux-release#60915161 that’s probably what you are after

Comment: https://githubmemory.com/repo/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/221
have a look here. did you do anything similar?

Comment: I have also raised an issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93668 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error once I integrated Firebase into my flutter application.
This may not be a legitimate solution to this error, but here is what I did.

1. Upgraded `minSdkVersion` to 24(ANDROID/APP/build.gradle)

Usually firebase required us to upgrade the SDK to 19. I changed it to a higher SDK(in this case 24) for testing purposes.

2. Clean & Build gradle

I then cleaned the our android gradle files with the following cmds;

- `cd android` -> if you are at the root of your flutter project
- `./gradlew clean` -> To clean the gradle environment
- `./gradlew build` -> To build again on a clean environment

3. Cleaned and run in the flutter environment

- `cd ..` -> To return to the root
- `flutter clean` -> Cleans the flutter workspace
- `flutter pub get` -> Gets back the deleted packages and dependencies
- `flutter run` -> Runs the application

I hope this helps out someone, as I said it is not a legitimate solution, but it is what worked for me. If this fails. Also consider checking the compatibility of the JAVA and Gradle SDK versions by;

- `cd android` -> Going back into android project.
- `java --version` -> To check for java version.
- `./gradlew --version` -> to check the gradle version.
  Using the commands above, you may check the compatibility [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

I changed `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'`  which was was located at `android\build.gradle` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'` downgrading the version, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

adding these lines to AndroidManifest.xml file solved this issue for me:

```
<meta-data
android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

but a warning appeared on Run console:

```
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21657): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can temporarily get rid of the error by including

```
<meta-data
android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

in your manifest file, as the other answers say. you would then be seeing a warning instead of the error but your app should run fine. This is apparantly an issue with running the flutter splash screen plugin on some of the Android devices as discussed in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93668

Answer (score -2):

I have solved this problem.
If you are using flutter_splash_screen package, you should delete this package and update AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml.

Comment: But if you're using that package, you'll be using it for a reason :-)