# DP cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true i need help fixing this error on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried to change the version of gradle, this error shows when i try to run the project on debug mode and release mode and didn't have any effect on this error, this project has firebase configrations too and authorized firebase project, i have been with this error since 8 hours till now what should i do to fix it???

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator(20774): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:34917/vYX8PcG07hY=/ws
Syncing files to device SM N770F...
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: false
E/flutter (20774): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter (20774): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter (20774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20774): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter (20774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20774): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter (20774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20774): #3      Config.initFirebase (package:social_media_app/utils/config.dart:5:5)
E/flutter (20774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20774): #4      main (package:social_media_app/main.dart:16:3)
E/flutter (20774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20774): 
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=false visible=true
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} of ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity]
D/OpenGLRenderer(20774): setSurface called with nullptr
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(0,0)4 dur=4 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false fn=-1
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: false
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): stopped(false) old=true
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(20774): isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=false this: DecorView@bd92290[MainActivity]
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(20774): removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@bd92290[MainActivity]
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): stopped(false) old=false
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(20774): isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: windowingMode=1 isFullscreen=true isPopOver=false isHidden=false skipActivityType=false isHandlerType=false this: DecorView@bd92290[MainActivity]
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(20774): removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@bd92290[MainActivity]
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} of ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity]
D/OpenGLRenderer(20774): setSurface called with nullptr
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=7 res=0x7 s={true 482270457856} ch=true fn=-1
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): windowStopped(false) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2400} of ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity]
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11420 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4193 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2919 
D/hw-ProcessState(20774): Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
D/OpenGLRenderer(20774): eglCreateWindowSurface
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): pST: sr = Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) sw = 1080 sh = 2400
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): pST: mTmpTransaction.apply, mTmpTransaction = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@2bdeb87
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): updateSurface: mVisible = true mSurface.isValid() = true
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): updateSurface: mSurfaceCreated = false surfaceChanged = true visibleChanged = true
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2400}
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): surfaceChanged (1080,2400) 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2400}
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] dp(2) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1375 android.view.SurfaceView.lambda$new$1$SurfaceView:254 android.view.SurfaceView$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onPreDraw:2 
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] pdf(1) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.notifyDrawFinished:599 android.view.SurfaceView.performDrawFinished:586 android.view.SurfaceView.$r8$lambda$st27mCkd9jfJkTrN_P3qIGKX6NY:0 
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): pST: sr = Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2361) sw = 1080 sh = 2361
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): pST: mTmpTransaction.apply, mTmpTransaction = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@2bdeb87
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): updateSurface: mVisible = true mSurface.isValid() = true
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): updateSurface: mSurfaceCreated = true surfaceChanged = false visibleChanged = false
I/SurfaceView@d397f51(20774): surfaceChanged (1080,2361) 1 #5 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{d397f51 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2361}
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] dp(2) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1375 android.view.SurfaceView.setFrame:675 android.view.View.layout:24458 
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] pdf(1) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.notifyDrawFinished:599 android.view.SurfaceView.performDrawFinished:586 android.view.SurfaceView.$r8$lambda$st27mCkd9jfJkTrN_P3qIGKX6NY:0 
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
I/ViewRootImpl@755d7bc[MainActivity](20774): [DP] cancelDraw null isViewVisible: true
Application finished.
```

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933734/console-messages-in-flutter ?

Comment: yes but still no effect

Comment: any luck @RayenMichael